# I want to use a python code in django template

Tags: python, django

I have this code in my django template:

```
{% for i in concedii %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ i.7 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ i.8 }}
        </td>
        {% for d in luna %}
            <td class="text-center">
                    {% if d.0 > i.5 > d.1%}
                        {{ i.4 }}
                    {% endif %}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And inside this code I would like to implement this code:

```
val1 = 23.04 # this is the d.0 from django template above
val2 = 29.04 # this is the d.1 from django template above

tobe1 = 24.04 # this is the i.5 from django template above
tobe2 = 27.04 # this is the i.6 from django template above

if all(val1 < x < val2 for x in (tobe1, tobe2)):
    print(saptamani)
```

Comment: OK.  So what's the problem?

Comment: You can’t put Python code in the Django template. The Django philosophy is that you should avoid putting complex logic in the template - do it in the view and pass the result to the template context. If you really want to embed it in the template, look at [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag)